# Putty skips installation wizard

Tags: installation, wizard, putty

I downloaded the putty.exe installer for Windows x86 from here-
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
I am running windows 7.
When I run the executable it goes straight to the Putty Configuration window without running the Setup Process. I don't see the Welcome dialog shown in the first image here-
https://www.openshift.com/page/install-and-setup-putty-ssh-client-for-windows
So I can't save a configuration and reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to download the "Windows installer" and not just the .exe. The .exe file is standalone and does not require an install. Either way it has the same functionality.